# MVC 4 can not find assemblies and shows file structure

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

have a mvc 4 application. I have changed "Copy Local" property for all referenced assemblies (even system.dll). each time I deploy it to WinHost (Asp.NET hosting) it complains and says could not load file or assembly. I deleted the Bin folder on WinHost redeployed everything, each time I deploy the application, it shows one of the following errors

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm' or one of its dependencies. ....
  
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.oData' or one of its dependencies. ...

Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease' or one of its dependencies. ...

Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFrameWork' or one of its dependencies. ...
```

I removed EntityFrameWork by running unistall-package EntityFrameWork, it had some dependencies so I had to remove them first.

Now When I browse to my application it shows the file structure.
I have two questions:

1. why it cannot find assemblies while all are there in bin folder? it must be something else than assemblies.
2. why it shows my file structure now after I removed EntityFramework and its dependencies?

   I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I think it is probably looking for specific version of your assemblies which is missing.

Comment: Thank you HBhatia, I have checked even the verisons. if the version was the issue then it should generate same error every time, but it generates different error each time I deploy.